# How to use transaction journaling

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions

[Release notes](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.7.0) of Geth 1.7 mention a new feature: local transactions journaling.

Unfortunately, I didn't find anywhere in the doc how to activate or configure this feature, and I am currently getting this warning after a node restart:

```
Failed to journal local transaction      err="no active journal"
```

Any idea of how to activate this and/or specify journaling path? Thanks.

Comment: the same problem, anybody has the answer ?